# Mudar a cor de uma caixa no menu horizontal

Tags: css, xhtml

Estou fazendo um menu horizontal e quero que cada elemento desse menu tenha uma caixa de 20px. Agora quero que ao passar com o mouse por cimam essa caixa mude de cor.

Para isso pensei que se usasse o `a:hover` resolvia o problema. Só que não. Ele ao invés de mudar a cor da caixa muda só a cor de volta de cada palavra.

Depois pensei que dando um `padding` ao `a:hover` resolvia. Só que não.

Vejam o exemplo: atenção que o objetivo é a cor do ahover ser preenchida toda a caixa dos elementos.

### HTML

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="inicio.html">Inicio</a></li>
 <li><a href="ajuda.html">Ajuda</a></li>
 <li><a href="contatos.html">Contatos</a></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
ul {
   display: inline;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}

li {
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 12px;
}

a:hover {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/r8cum7q4/2/

Answer (score 2):

Você não definiu o tamanho da caixa do **li:hover**, quando definir um tamanho para ele, a cor vai preencher todo o espaço. Testa assim:

```
li:hover {

margin: 10px; padding: 12px;
background-color: red;

}
```

Comment: Apenas para exemplo do seu método: http://jsfiddle.net/r8cum7q4/

Comment: Obrigado. O problema é que eu tenho 2 menus horizontais na mesma página e não estou a saber fazer para eles terem cores diferentes.

Comment: Sabe usar ID's ou Classes ?

Comment: Como o DeeSouza falou, é so usar classes.

Comment: Sei. Só que não estou a saber aplicar nos menus horizontais. O livro que li sobre o assunto já era antigo não falava de menus horizontais. E de listas só falava o basico. Não sei se conhece o livro "use a cabeça com xhtml css". Andei a ver outros livros mais atuais mas não consigo encontrar nada especifico sobre este assunto.

Comment: Veja esse exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/r8cum7q4/2/

Comment: Ou esse https://jsfiddle.net/r8cum7q4/3/ o do DeeSouza é melhor...

Comment: Já testei fora do site e em principio consegui :) Valeu MESMO pela ajuda. Já agora conhecem artigos/sites ou livros que abordem mais sobre este tema? Obrigado.

Comment: É assim mesmo que começa, bons estudos para você!

Answer (score 0):

Acrescenta o padding no li a, exemplo:

```css
ul {
   display: inline;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}

li {
   margin: 10px; 
}

li a {
   padding: 12px;
}

li a:hover {
   background-color: red;
}
```